# Month End Data for SSRS Report

Tags: python, sql, date, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I am attempting to build an SSRS report that calls data from a shared data source. I need to build a table with several fields:

Loan No, Borrower Name, Balance Today, Balance Month End

I have created two data sources that are redundant; one for the date the report is ran (Balance today) and one to get the data from a date in the past (Balance Month End).

In Python I am able to set a variable based upon an elif to get the previous month end (cant be a holiday or a weekend) using this logic:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date(2018, 6, 19)
monthend = datetime.date(2018, 12, 14)

if today >= datetime.date(2018, 6, 1) and today < datetime.date(2018, 6, 30):
    monthend = datetime.date(2018, 5, 31)
    print(monthend)
elif today >= datetime.date(2018, 7, 1) and today < datetime.date(2018, 7, 31):
    monthend = datetime.date(2018, 6, 29)
    print(monthend)
elif today >= datetime.date(2018, 8, 1) and today < datetime.date(2018, 8, 31):
    monthend = datetime.date(2018, 7, 31)
    print(monthend)
elif today >= datetime.date(2018, 9, 1) and today < datetime.date(2018, 9, 30):
    monthend = datetime.date(2018, 8, 31)
    print(monthend)
elif today >= datetime.date(2018, 10, 1) and today < datetime.date(2018,
                           10, 31):
    monthend = datetime.date(2018, 9, 28)
    print(monthend)
elif today >= datetime.date(2018, 11, 1) and today < datetime.date(2018,
                           11, 30):
    monthend = datetime.date(2018, 10, 31)
    print(monthend)
elif today >= datetime.date(2018, 12, 1) and today < datetime.date(2018,
                           12, 31):
    monthend = datetime.date(2018, 11, 30)
    print(monthend)
elif today >= datetime.date(2019, 1, 1) and today < datetime.date(2019,
                           1, 31):
    monthend = datetime.date(2018, 12, 31)
    print(monthend)
```

How would I write this logic either on the report side or db side to get the previous month end date parameter?

Thanks

Comment: In SQL Server, use EOMONTH() and DATEADD() to get your previous month ranges or dates. I'm sure that would have come up when you searched 'SQL Server previous month end date'.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME = CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, - DAY(@Today), @Today) [Last Day of Last Month]
```